# Can't update Rubymine due to permission issue

Tags: permissions

I'm trying to update Rubymine to 8.0.4.

The UPDATE button was not active due to a permission issue, and I got this alert:

> RubyMine does not have write access to /opt/Rubymine. Please run it by
>   a privileged user to update.

Then I tried running `sudo ./rubymine.sh` from the /bin folder, but I get the following error:

```
[  29530]   WARN - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Watcher terminated with exit code 0 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m; support was removed in 8.0
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I'm stuck, any clue about what to do next? Thanks

Comment: A quick workaround would be to do `chmod -R 777 /opt/Rubymine` to make it world writable / readable.

Comment: sweet, it worked. I think there might be a cleaner way to achieve this though ...

Comment: put the permissions back afterwards